# rowcount query in Oracle 8i

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle8i

I have a table Department_history and  here is the count of records for each department.

```
select department_name, Id, count(1) total_rows_COUNT from Department_history
where 
group by Department_history,id
order by 2 desc
```

result:

```
department_name         ID     total_rows_COUNT 
Accounting            4564     556
Finance               3434     671
Marketing             4353  234
IT                  1233    454
```

I want to keep only the 10 records for each department in the table.

if run this below query for each department like this, it works.

```
delete from Department_history a1 
where 
and a1.report_runtime NOT IN
(
   select report_runtime
   from (
       select a.*, rank() over ( partition by department_name, id  order by report_runtime desc) r
       from Department_history a
    ) rs
     where r <= 10 and department_name = 'Accounting'

)
and department_name = 'Accounting'
```

But I don't want to individually run this  deletion for each department. 
how can I run one query that deletes the data for each department_name (if it is >10 records). I tries this. but it doesn't work.

```
delete from Department_history a1 
where 
and a1.report_runtime NOT IN
(
   select report_runtime
   from (
       select a.*, rank() over ( partition by department_name, id  order by report_runtime desc) r
       from Department_history a
    ) rs
     where r <= 10 

)
```

Can someone please advise?

Comment: Your first query selects 2 columns, but your output 3? In your second query is "Department_history = 'Accounting'" a correct condition? I thought that was your table name, not column name. Is a `where and` syntax working for you? Is `id` not having unique values in your table Department_history? If it is not unique, then naming it `id` is really confusing. Does it uniquely identify the department_name? If so, why do you partition by both? Is report_runtime a column with unique values? Maybe the primary key?

Comment: In this [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6643e/1) I put the generic `delete` statement in the left panel, and a `select` in the right one to see whether it deleted the 3 records it should delete. It works correctly. This is Oracle 11g, so maybe your issue is related to Oracle 8i. Put please provide your table structure (data types, primary key, ...)

Comment: just thinking about the ID in partition by... do you really need it? if you want to group by department_name it looks that you can remove ID... so it should be over ( partition by department_name order by report_runtime desc)

Comment: Hi, ID is a unique value, and corrected the above query with the correct column name now. yes. the partition should be done by both department_name and ID. however, lets say if i can remove partition by ID, what is the query to delete everything in a single statement?

Comment: So what is the primary key on `department_history`?  Based on your first query, `ID` clearly isn't unique.

Comment: your initial query looks ok if you delete the ID from partition by

Comment: @sstan - Id is unique for each department name. But this table has the multiple rows of the same department-name with the Id. And the record gets inserted everyday in the table. for ex: we have 100 rows accounting department-name with the Id . Only difference in the 100 rows are report-runtime. This runtime varies for everyday with the current date. (10/20/2015 05:06:30, next day it will be, 10/21/2015 05:10:00.

Comment: @are - you mean the first query with the department_name ='Accounting' ? That works fine and deletes the records if there are more than 10. That is not my problem. My question is, I don't want to specify the department_name and run this query to delete the records for each departments (like this - department_name = 'Accounting' ) . I need to run a single query that deletes the records for each department if there are more than 10 records.

Comment: I updated my answer see. below

Answer (score 0):

test sample:

```
create table tst as select owner, view_name from all_views;

delete from tst
  where owner||'::'||view_name in
(  
select owner||'::'||view_name from (
select owner, view_name, rank() over (partition by owner order by view_name) r from tst
) where r > 10
)
```

your updated sql:

```
delete from Department_history
where id NOT IN
(
   select id
   from (
       select id, rank() over ( partition by department_name  
order by report_runtime desc) rnk
from Department_history
    ) s
     where s.rnk <= 10    
)
```

Comment: The OP has a question about a department_history table and you answer something about all_views? Did you intend to answer another question about deleting database views?

Comment: see syntax... it shouldn't be a problem to change names of tables when script works as required

Comment: `where (owner, view_name) in (select owner, view_name ...)` would be much better than the concatenation

Comment: it would be. but I don't remember does 8i support the syntax or not

Comment: I suppose, owner is a depertment_name and view_name is a report_runtime from my query. basically i need the records to be deleted where report_runtime not in (...). But in your example, you have put owner,view_name inside IN clause. so it is going to delete the latest 10 records. but requirement is to keep the last 10 records and delete the remaining ones for all the department_names

Comment: you can change order by, for example: (partition by owner order by view_name desc)

Comment: The updated query will not work for me. Because ID is unique for each department name. But this table has the multiple rows of the same department-name with the Id. And the record gets inserted everyday in the table. for ex: we have 100 rows accounting department-name with the Id . Only difference in the 100 rows are report-runtime. This runtime varies for everyday with the current date. (10/20/2015 05:06:30, next day it will be, 10/21/2015 05:10:00.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It's similar to what you already tried, but the `not in` clause should be checking against all 3 identifying columns, `department_name, id, report_runtime`, not just `report_runtime`.  Otherwise, you might accidentally delete the wrong rows.

I also used `row_number` instead of `rank`.  I think it's the better choice for your requirement. Though based on your description of the data, I don't think it actually makes a difference in this case.

```
delete from department_history
 where (department_name, id, report_runtime)
   not in (select department_name, id, report_runtime
             from (select department_name, id, report_runtime,
                          row_number() over (partition by department_name, id order by report_runtime desc) as rn
                     from department_history)
            where rn <= 10)
```

Comment: I executed this query for 1000 records and it works. Thank you! 
Now I am executing this in the actual table that has 600980 records 
and it is running more than 30 minutes and it is still going.
I created an index on department_name,id and report_runtime. but still no luck.i feel like  it is a long execution time for  600k records

Comment: Personally, if I had to do something like this, I wouldn't try to delete the rows like this.  I would use the subquery to create a new table with only the data I want, then drop the original table, and finally would rename the new table back to `department_history`.  Assuming the `select` runs efficiently, I think this would run a lot faster.  See here for more info: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::NO:RP:P11_QUESTION_ID:2345591157689

Comment: That's a good idea. I think that's what I'm going to do. Thanks for your time to check on this.